# Python can't display data on widgets from inside on_message websocket function

Tags: python, websocket

I was successfull retrieving data and displaying it using print but somehow I am unable to load it into a table widget.
self.ui.tableWidget.setItem ( 0, 1, QTableWidgetItem(current_price)) and self.ui.tableWidget.setItem ( 1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(current_price))
don´t display data.
I don't know if I am doing something wrong , I just started with python and websockets

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

# Important:
# You need to run the following command to generate the ui_form.py file
#     pyside6-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py, or
#     pyside2-uic form.ui -o ui_form.py
from ui_form import Ui_Widget
import websocket
import json

class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Widget()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect (self.click_Boton)


    def click_Boton(self) :
        #websocket.enableTrace(True)
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=adausdt@ticker/dotusdt@ticker/xrpusdt@ticker/roseusdt@ticker/runeusdt@ticker/avaxusdt@ticker/xlmusdt@ticker/hbarusdt@ticker/fluxusdt@ticker/qntusdt@ticker/linkusdt@ticker", on_message = self.on_message, on_error = self.on_error, on_close = self.on_close)
        #ws.on_open = self.on_open
        #ws.on_message = self.on_message(
        ws.run_forever()
   

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        data = json.loads(message)
        #print (data)
        current_asset = (data['data']['s'])
        current_price = (data['data']['c'])
        print (current_asset)
        print (current_price)

        if (current_asset == 'ADAUSDT'):
            print ('Asset if ada')
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem ( 0, 1, QTableWidgetItem(current_price))

        elif (current_asset == 'DOTUSDT'):
            print ('asset if dot')

            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem ( 1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(current_price))

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print(error)

    def on_close(self, ws):
            print("WebSocket closed")

    def on_open(self, ws):
        # Subscribe to the real-time price updates for the given symbol
        #symbol = 'btcusdt'
        #ws.send(json.dumps({"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": [f"{symbol_2}@ticker"], "id": 1}))
        print ('open')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I don,t know what to try , I am stuck

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe you doesn't get exactly `ADAUSDT`  or `DOTUSDT` and `==` gives `False` . Yyou could use `print()` inside `if/else` to see if this part of code is executed. You can even run `print( current_asset == 'ADAUSDT' , current_asset == 'DOTUSDT' )` to see if it gives `True`

Comment: I see other problem: in main thread you run `ws.run_forever()` which blocks `app.exec()` and GUI can't run loop which redraw window - so it can't show changes. And all GUI hangs. You may have to run `websocket` in separated thread - `QThread` and send result to main tread - probably using Signals

Comment: it seems `PySide2` has [QWebSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWebSockets/QWebSocket.html) and maybe it will work better with `app.exec()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code but I think all problem can be `ws.run_forever()` which runs forever and it blocks `app.exec()` which can't update/redraw widgets in window - so it can't display changes, and even it hangs GUI because it can't react for buttton's clicks, etc.

Normally it would need to run `websocket` in separated thread but I found `PyQT` has `QWebSocket` and it works for me:

```
from PySide6.QtWebSockets import QWebSocket
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl

url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=adausdt@ticker/dotusdt@ticker/xrpusdt@ticker/roseusdt@ticker/runeusdt@ticker/avaxusdt@ticker/xlmusdt@ticker/hbarusdt@ticker/fluxusdt@ticker/qntusdt@ticker/linkusdt@ticker"

self.ws = QWebSocket()

self.ws.connected.connect(self.on_open)
self.ws.disconnected.connect(self.on_close)
self.ws.error.connect(self.on_error)

self.ws.textMessageReceived.connect(self.on_message)

self.ws.open(QUrl(url))
```

It doesn't need to run any `run_forever` because `app.exec()` makes all job.

---

Full working code:

I used `QLabel` because I don't have your `UI` file.

[image]

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtWebSockets import QWebSocket
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
import json

class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()        
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self, text='WebSocket')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click_Boton)

        self.label1 = QLabel(self, text='Label1: ?')
        
        self.label2 = QLabel(self, text='Label2: ?')
        
        vbox.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label2)
        
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        
    def click_Boton(self) :
        url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=adausdt@ticker/dotusdt@ticker/xrpusdt@ticker/roseusdt@ticker/runeusdt@ticker/avaxusdt@ticker/xlmusdt@ticker/hbarusdt@ticker/fluxusdt@ticker/qntusdt@ticker/linkusdt@ticker"
        
        self.ws = QWebSocket()
        
        self.ws.connected.connect(self.on_open)
        self.ws.disconnected.connect(self.on_close)
        self.ws.error.connect(self.on_error)

        self.ws.textMessageReceived.connect(self.on_message)
        
        self.ws.open(QUrl(url))
        #, on_message = self.on_message, on_error = self.on_error, on_close = self.on_close)
   
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('on_message')
        
        data = json.loads(message)
        #print (data)
        
        current_asset = (data['data']['s'])
        current_price = (data['data']['c'])
        #print(current_asset)
        #print(current_price)

        if current_asset == 'ADAUSDT':
            text = f'ADAUSDT: {current_price}'
            print(text)
            self.label1.setText(text)
            #self.ui.tableWidget.setItem ( 0, 1, QTableWidgetItem(current_price))

        elif current_asset == 'DOTUSDT':
            text = f'DOTUSDT: {current_price}'
            print(text)
            self.label2.setText(text)
            #self.ui.tableWidget.setItem ( 1, 1, QTableWidgetItem(current_price))

    def on_error(self, error):
        print('on_error')
        print(error)

    def on_close(self):
        print("on_close")

    def on_open(self):
        # Subscribe to the real-time price updates for the given symbol
        #symbol = 'btcusdt'
        #ws.send(json.dumps({"method": "SUBSCRIBE", "params": [f"{symbol_2}@ticker"], "id": 1}))
        print('on_open')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

---

Pages which I visited to create answer:

- Doc: [PySide2/QtWebSockets/QWebSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWebSockets/QWebSocket.html)
- Doc: [Qt WebSockets 6.6.1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebsockets-index.html) (in `C/C++`)
- [Qt WebSockets Examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwebsockets-examples.html) (in `C/C++`)
- Source code for one of examples: [EchoClient](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebsockets.git/tree/examples/websockets/echoclient?h=6.6) (in `C/C++`)
- Example in Python: [python qt websocket example-掘金](https://juejin.cn/s/python%20qt%20websocket%20example)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer exceeds the limits of an answer you just made my code there , I would invite you a drink or smoke but as I can´t do that just pass me an address and I will send you some satoshis.

Comment: @Christian_uy if answer helped you then you could mark it as accepted, and later you can upvote it. If you means `BTC` then I didn't expect reward but it reminded me that I had forgotten wallet with some `micro BTC` :) You may try 13HrdHvu1yfFRDvXzPSjDPgsPZBpxsbMqY if you want :)

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted but apparently I can´t upvote yet. The BTC is on it's way .

Comment: you still have low `reputation score` so you may have to wait few minutes or hours to upvote. BTC is in my wallet :) Thanks.