# Tkinter button not responding via thread but works otherwise

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am working on small tkinter gui app in which I am fetching real time stock prices and place orders at the same time, I have created couple of Daemon threads that are fetching real time data over websocket as follows :

```
def start_feed(api, subscribe_list):
    print("start_feed function is called....")

    def event_handler_feed_update(tick_data):
        global gData=tick_data
        #This is where I receive live data over websocket

        
    def event_handler_order_update(orderNo):
        print(orderNo)

    def open_callback(threaded=True):
        global feed_opened
        feed_opened = True

    api.start_websocket(
        order_update_callback=event_handler_order_update,
        subscribe_callback=event_handler_feed_update,
        socket_open_callback=open_callback,
    )

    while feed_opened == False:
        pass

    api.subscribe(subscribe_list)
    time.sleep(2)

def live_feed():
    print("Inside live_feed function")    
    global myLabel1
    print()
    print(gData)        
    time.sleep(0.15)
    #this is an infinite loop in which I fetching new data after every 0.15 seconds and implementing logic 

t2 = Thread(target=start_feed(api, subscribe_list))
t2.setDaemon(True)
t2.start()
t1 = Thread(target=live_feed)
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()
```

Then I have created a basic tkinter gui with button n other widgets, below is the screenshot when button pressed it's working as expected when used non threaded code to call the function
[image: This is how gui looks like and you can see live feed in output window on the rhs]

The working button code -

```
buy_PE = tk.Button(root, text="Buy PE", command=buy_PE).pack()
```

But when I use threading in it button is not calling the function at all, only press action happens n no function call, here is the code -

```
buy_PE = tk.Button(root, text="Buy PE", command=Thread(target=buy_PE).start()).pack()
```

[image: Not working screenshot]

Here is the function that I am trying to call via button press -

```
# Buy PE function -
def buy_PE():
    global pe_tradingSymbol
    global final_quantity
    PE_buy_order_placed.config(text="inside buy_PE()")
    orderNo = api.place_order(
        buy_or_sell="B",        
        tradingsymbol=pe_tradingSymbol,
        quantity=final_quantity,        
        price_type="MKT",        
    )

    PE_buy_order_placed.config(text=orderNo)
```

Here api is a global object

So my question, why this button is not calling the function when used thread but working well otherwise ? is it because of the already running t1,t2 threads in the background ? is there any way I can speed up the button response time in tkinter, it feels a bit laggy when I press a button, almost takes a second to respond back, anyway to speed that up ?

Comment: few days ago I answered on question about `websocket` in `PyQt6` - and this `GUI` has special class `QWebSocket` which doesn't need `threading`. So maybe you should use `PyQt` instead of `Tkinter`

Comment: You have two common mistakes in one line with `Button` - `var = Button().pack()` assign to variable result from `pack()` which always returns `None`. If you want to keep button in variable then you should do it in two steps `var = Button()` and `var.pack()`

Comment: second common mistake: `command=` needs `calllback` - it means function's name without `()`, and when you click button then `tkinter` will use `()` to run this function. But you have `thread.start()` - so it runs `start()` at once and it returns `None` to `command=`. And when you click button then it tries to run `None()` - and you should get error message in console. You have to use `command=Thread(target=buy_PE).start` without `()`

Comment: I see another mistake - you use the same name `buy_PE` to keep button - `buy_PE = Button(...)` and as function's name `def buy_PE()`. And this can make problem when you will try click button because `target=buy_PE` may try to run `button` (or `None` if you use `buy_PE = Button(...).pack()`) instead your function. You have to rename one of them.

Comment: question about `PyQt6` and `QWebSocket` - [Python can't display data on widgets from inside on\_message websocket function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77655714/python-cant-display-data-on-widgets-from-inside-on-message-websocket-function/77656459#77656459)

Comment: BTW: `tkitner` may have another problem: It doesn't like to use widgets in threads - so you may have problem with `PE_buy_order_placed.config(text=...)`. You may have to send values to main thread using `queue`, and `tkinter` may need `after(miliisecond, callback)` to run periodically function which will check queue and update widget.

Answer (score 1):

I can't run code but I see three problems in one line

```
buy_PE = tk.Button(root, text="Buy PE", command=Thread(target=buy_PE).start()).pack()
```

The most important: `command=` needs `callback` - it means function's name without `()` and when you press button then it will use `()` to run it.
So you need

```
command=Thread(target=buy_PE).start
```

without `()` after `start`.

Your current code starts thread when you start program. And `command` has nothing to run. Eventually it may raise error if `start()` returns something strange because `tkinter` will try to use it as function.

Second: you use the same name `buy_PE` to keep button `buy_PE = tk.Button(...)` and as function's name `def buy_PE()` and sometimes it can make problem because thread may try to run your button instead of function. You should rename one of them.

Third: code `buy_PE = tk.Button(...).pack()` assigns `None` to variable because `pack()` (and `grid()`, `place()`) always gives `None`. You should do it in two steps

```
buy_PE = tk.Button(...)
buy_PE.pack()
```

---

Maybe you may have another problem. `tkinter` (like many GUIs) doesn't like to use widgets in threads - so you may have problem with `PE_buy_order_placed.config(text=...)`. You may have to send values to main thread using `queue`, and `tkinter` may need `after(miliisecond, callback)` to run periodically function which will check `queue` and update widget.

Comment: Thank you for the input sir and sorry for the late reply, it was background thread which was slowing down the whole thing, its resolved now, thank you for your input though, sir.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't run the code and check because I have to type all the missing parts and recheck. I assume this could be the problem.

When you call a Thread, it takes a target function as its argument. Since you can't call function with argument directly, Try as follows:

```
buy_PE = tk.Button(root, text="Buy PE", command= lamda :Thread(target=buy_PE).start()).pack()
```

Implement the same kind of changes with all threads called by any buttons or any other widgets.

Kindly confirm in comments if it works or otherwise also. I'm following this question manually.

Comment: Sorry for not able to share the whole code at first place, it's been fixed now, thanks you for your input though.

Comment: @ScalperVegeta, Of course I don't expect the entire code.  I wanted to know whether my code works as expected. Could you please check and confirm if possible?

Comment: Yes, it does work, after adding lambda notation threads started to work. Once again, thank you for your input.